# Multiformat date validation in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I tried validating two date formats Y and Y-m : eg: 2022 or 2022-05
I tried creating costum validation,

```
     Validator::extend('date_multi_format', function($attribute, $value, $formats) {
        // iterate through all formats
        foreach($formats as $format) {
  
          // parse date with current format
          $parsed = date_parse_from_format($format, $value);
  
          // if value matches given format return true=validation succeeded 
          if ($parsed['error_count'] === 0 && $parsed['warning_count'] === 0) {
            return true;
          }
        }
  
        // value did not match any of the provided formats, so return false=validation failed
        return false;
      });
```

it is not validating Y-m format eg: 2022-5
as i tried 'date' => 'date_multi_format: "Y-m" "Y"'

Comment: Have you registered the extended rule in **boot()** method of a service provider? Means is the above code in the boot method of a ServiceProvider?

Comment: yes, i have registered the extended rule in boot()